# "value can't be null" when adding JSON item to ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to load names from one file and add it to a listbox.
My code to load:

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    List<Purchaser> Purchasers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Purchaser>>(File.ReadAllText(file));
    Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
    listDOF.Items.Add(purchaser.Name);
}
```

But this give me an exception that said the value can't be null.
Making a test applying the Name value in one label instead of the listbox like label1.Text = purchaser.Name, let the label empty! So, I think the file is not being loaded or I'm doing something wrong.
For the List class, I have:

```
public class Purchaser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Paid { get; set; }
}
List<Purchaser> Purchasers = new List<Purchaser>();
```

The file is saved as I want but this do not load the Name value to the listbox.
Can someone give me a hand? I'm trying to do this during all day! Thanks!

Comment: Where do you use the deserialized object `Purchasers` ? What do you add a newly initialized object to `listDOF.Items` ?

Comment: I need to get the Name value and put in the listbox. Why is null? I want to read it from file. Is not by this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Purchaser().Name` is always null<sup>1</sup> and thus [`Items.Add(null)` throws an exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx).

To fix this error, *use* the JSON information - there is no need to create a new non-initialized Purchaser. For example,

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(file);
var purchasers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Purchaser>>(json);
// for each purchaser, add them to the list
for (var p in purchasers) {
  listDOF.Items.Add(p.Name ?? "{null}");
}
```

As stated, `ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add` does not accept null values. While the primary issue is fixed by using the information from the JSON note the additional use of the [null-coalescing operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Using this guard prevents an exception if someone really is missing a name (not to be confused with a blank name) - this should not happen, but be defensive!

---

<sup>1</sup> Null is the default value for reference types, including strings; since the (Name) property has not been assigned any other value, it is still the default - or null.

Comment: OK, `new Purchaser().Name` is null, but would this `listDOF.Items.Add(purchaser.Name);` throw an exception? Would adding null to a List throw exception?

Comment: @L.B In [WinForms ListBox, yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) - the value must not be null.

Comment: @user2864740 Now I'm having problem in remove the selected purchaser in the listbox from the List Purchasers.
In the click event of one button, I have:
`if(listDOF.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();
                Purchasers.Remove(purchaser);
                listDOF.Items.Remove(listDOF.SelectedItem);
            }`
But this is not working. How to remove from the List Purchasers the actual purchaser selected in the lisbox?

Comment: @Hypister Ask a different question after identify the specific problem issue and isolating a small test-case.

Comment: @Hypister However, do note that it is stemming from the same problem - using `new Purchaser()`, such that the Name is `null`. Update the Remove to remove the appropriate item (depending upon what the click button *should* do).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    var purchasers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Purchaser>>(File.ReadAllText(file));
    foreach(var purchaser in purchasers)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(purchaser.Name))
        {
            //nulls are not allowed
            continue;
        }
        listDOF.Items.Add(purchaser.Name);
    }
}
```

When you are doing this `Purchaser purchaser = new Purchaser();` your creating a new single instance that has no data other than default values.